# How to return a View in MVC with URL like this http://localhost/admin#sayhi

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Ok Here is the exact scenario:

I have a view named Index
I have a partial view (user control) named SayHi
I have an AdminController which has an Action named SayHi which doesn't do anything else

```
ViewData["Message"]  = "Hi There!";
```

I am using ajax to load partial views from the Index.aspx
so when I have the followinf url > http://localhost/Index#Sayhi sayhi partial view is called.

So all I need now is how in the controller to return this address
 I can't use View("Index#Sayhi")
And also if I use the RedirectUrl("index#sayhi") I lose the ViewData.

Please any help is appreciated
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the '#' character is used for page internal bookmark links and should not be used for server side logic. so linking to a page with your #sayhi url, the browser will go to that page and scroll down to a tag like this:

```
<a name="sayhi"></a>
```

If you want to pass `sayhi` into the action you should use ? instead and grab it from the request.

Comment: Thank you dalager, but I use # for ajax loading of different panels (just like new facebook mechanism)